# Why does Skywave only work for a small frequency band?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, microwaves, radio-frequency

So it is often said that waves in the HF band (3-30MHz) use skywave propagation to beam signals around the curvature of the Earth.

My question is why is there this narrow limit to what is able to make use of the Ionosphere to propagate signals around the Earth?

On the higher end of the limit when the wave/photon has more energy, is it more likely to interact with an ion or electron in the Ionosphere. Therefore I would expect it to be absorbed by the Ionosphere. Yet we know that higher frequency signals (1.1-1.5GHz) can penetrate the ionosphere as this is what GPS uses. Why is this?

On the lower end, I have no clue why they could not use skywave propagation.

Any explanation would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Penetrate through (vertically - several km of ionosphere) vs propagate 1000's of km through are two very different things.

Comment: I should probably clarify my main question is. Why are higher frequency signals able to penetrate the Ionosphere, despite the fact they have higher energy?

Comment: Frequencies above the plasma frequency of the order of say 15 MHz will be transmitted through the ionosphere. If you want to describe this in terms of photons, then you need to take into account the fact that there are now coherent interactions. So, the photon will interact with ions, but the effect of the many possible collisions will interfere with each other, the net result is then what you get out of the usual analysis of electromagnetic wave propagation through the plasma.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. Unfortunately my knowledge of quantum theory goes as far as particle wave duality and I don't know much about EM waves either. Could you explain it in simpler terms or is it too complex? Thank you once again.

Comment: Why is visible light able to penetrate through glass that has broad absorption bands in the infrared?